# Gravar registro do Json em variável

Tags: android, android-studio

olá, Estou consumindo um Json e recebo ela no meu `fragment`, pego apenas 2 registros e guardo em uma variável criada no inicio da classe, os 2 do tipo String, assim:

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        Link link = new Link();
        JSONArray json = response.optJSONArray("link");
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;

        try {
            jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(0);
            link.setTitulo(jsonObject.optString("titulo"));
            link.setLink(jsonObject.optString("link"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        titulo = link.getTitulo().toString();
        linkWeb = link.getLink().toString();
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), titulo + " - " + linkWeb, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Testei com o toast e está ok, O problema é que quando vou utilizar essas variáveis fora desse método, ele está como null. o que tem de errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu JSONObject esta sendo declarado dentro do metodo `onResponse(JSONObject response)`

Para voce conseguir acessar a variavel em outro metodo, vai ser necessario declarar a mesma globalmente.

Ex:

```
Classe pai {
  JSONArray jsonArrayGlobal;
  JSONObject jsonObjectGlobal;

  public void onResponse(JSONObject response){
     try {
        jsonArrayGlobal = jsonArrayGlobal.optJSONArray("link");
        jsonObjectGlobal = jsonArrayGlobal.getJSONObject(0);
        restante do seu try...
     }catch(JSONException e) {...}
  }

  public void outroMetodo() {
       //Aqui voce pode chamar seu Json que ja esta declarado no metodo acima
  }
}
```

Comment: Vlw #Davi Ferreira, resolveu!

Comment: opa, que bom! fico feliz em ter ajudado.